# Recurrence Relation Expansion

Tags: recurrence-relations

How does this recurrence relation simplify?

$X_n$ = $X_{n-1}$ + $2pqX_{n-1}$ - $qX_{n-1}$

It seems like some kind of binomial expansion but I am not sure.

Comment: If you really meant $X_n=(1+2pq-q)X_{n-1}$ then that's simply a geometric progression.